# Usage of ing in sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I can not understand how agreeing have been used here?

"The Indian statement on Saturday noted that in the context of both sides **agreeing** on the need to solve the issue,"it was highlighted that completion on disengagement in other area would pave the way for two sides to consider de-escalation of forces and ensure full restoration of peace and tranquility and enable progress in bilateral relation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The indian statement on saturday noted that in the context of both sides agreeing on the need to solve the issue,"it was highlighted that completion on disengagement in other area would pave the way for two sides to consider de-escalation of forces and ensure full restoration of peace and tranquility and enable progress in bilateral relation".

The word 'agreeing' is a gerund and should be preceded by a possessive.  The noun phrase *both sides' agreeing* is then the object of preposition *of*.

I have noticed a few unusual points in the passage: missing are the apostrophe for the possessive of 'sides' and capital letters for the proper nouns; extra is a quotation mark, after 'issue'.

Incorporating these observations, I suggest the following for the first part of the passage

> "The [I]ndian statement on [S]aturday noted that in the context of *both sides' agreeing* on the need to solve the issue,[ ]it was highlighted..."